# Revit API Curves obtained from the edge

Tags: c#, revit-api

I have 3 rebar in a structural element.

[image: Rebar]

And using the [AsCurve](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2019/4d780a44-c713-036f-840f-605527bbb2ce.htm) method I draw the edge lines but something unexpected happens.

```
foreach (Edge borde in solido.Edges)
{
    Curve curva = borde.AsCurve();

    curvas.Add(curva);
}
```

I project those curves onto the view plane and then call [NewDetailCurve](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2019/9a8bd0d3-00dc-7a1c-39dd-e891899764ce.htm).

```
public static Curve ProyectarCurvaSobrePlano(View vista, Curve curva)
{
    List<XYZ> puntos = new List<XYZ>();

    Curve curvaProyectada = curva;
                
    foreach (XYZ punto in curva.Tessellate().ToList())
    {
        puntos.Add(ProyectarPuntoSobrePlano(vista, punto));
    }

    if (curva is Line)
    {
        curvaProyectada = Line.CreateBound(puntos[0], puntos[1]);
    }

    if (curva is Arc)
    {
        if (puntos.Count > 2)
        {
            curvaProyectada = Arc.Create(puntos[0], puntos[puntos.Count - 1], puntos[1]);
        }
    }

    if (curva is HermiteSpline)
    {
        HermiteSpline spline = curva as HermiteSpline;

        bool periodo = spline.IsPeriodic;

        HermiteSpline Hermite = HermiteSpline.Create(puntos, periodo);

        curvaProyectada = NurbSpline.CreateCurve(Hermite);
    }

    return curvaProyectada;
}
```

On the side where bar 1 has the hook (side B) bar 2 does not join the lines completely but that does not happen on side A.

[image: Problem]

Using revit lookup, I investigated the arc (left) and line (right) points using the [Tessellate method](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2019/f95f3199-3251-c708-c5a3-a0e9ef95ecfa.htm) but they both appear to be the same point. The problem always occurs in the corner where the hook of bar 1 is located, if bar 1 is removed, the lines join them without problems.

[image: LookUp]

After reading Jeremy Tammik post I still can't find any possible solution. [Sort curves](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2013/03/sort-and-orient-curves-to-form-a-contiguous-loop.html), [Sorting face](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2015/01/autodesk-internship-in-california-and-sorting-edges.html#3), [ExporterIfcUtils](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2015/01/exporterifcutils-curve-loop-sort-and-validate.html).

Comment: I cannot guess off-hand what might be the problem. Please submit a [complete minimal reproducible case](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#1b) that I can share with the development team for debugging and in-house analysis:

Comment: @JeremyTammik I uploaded to [github](https://github.com/kevinzurro/JumpForRevit) the complete addin with a file called "Instructions" where it details the step by step. I tried to name the methods where the lines are created in Revit in such a way that there is no confusion when it comes to understanding the operation of the addin. Inside the "Example" folder is a minimal reproducible case of the problem. I tried isolating the lines of code in a separate file as you [suggest](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#1b) but to no avail. I’m eager to receive your feedback

Comment: Thank you for isolating the steps required. Could you simplify it a lot further, please?  I find it a bit confusing to read your instructions and wonder how to execute them. Optimally, you could implement a complete minimal macro or add-in that enables the development team to observe the problematic behaviour with one single click, as described in the description of a [reproducible test case](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#1b). Thank you!

Comment: @JeremyTammik I was able to isolate the code and put it inside a [Revit macro](https://github.com/kevinzurro/JumpForRevit/tree/main/Example) in such a way that it reproduces the problem. I appreciate your response.

Comment: Thank you very much. I still have one little but significant problem submitting this to the development team: I simply do not quite understand what your exact issue is. My main stumbling block is the sentence `On the side where bar 1 has the hook ... bar 2 does not join the lines completely but that does not happen on side A`. Can you clarify exactly what the problem is, i.e., the expected result versus what you observe happening. Thank you, and sorry for being obtuse... I am not a structural expert, so I have little idea of what you are doing there.

Comment: @JeremyTammik I have created a [new tutorial](https://github.com/kevinzurro/JumpForRevit/blob/main/Instructions.md) on the obtained and expected results of the problem. The main problem is to move the lines and arcs without throwing an error.
I also posed some questions, which if possible, can be answered by the development team or by you. Cheers

Comment: I raised the issue [internally](https://autodesk.slack.com/archives/C01MQR3NTM3/p1665480459099159) with the development team and asked that someone more knowledgeable take a look at it.

Comment: @JeremyTammik Thank you very much for your help. I look forward to any feedback from the development team, as I've been thinking over and over for several weeks about what could be causing the problem.